Access network share in macOS without mounting it
In Windows I can access a network share either using the mounted drive:
file_path = 'V:\path\to\files'
list_of_files = os.listdir(file_path)

or alternatively using the network address:
file_path = '//our.server.de/share/data/path/to/files'
list_of_files = os.listdir(file_path)

How can I do this in macOS? I know I can mount the network share using smb and access it like this:
file_path = '//Volumes/data/path/to/files'
list_of_files = os.listdir(file_path)

But is there a way on macOS using Python to access the network address 'directly', without mounting it beforehand?

You mount it. That's the way to go. And BTW it's not a real programming topic.
